# Dealing with (merging) 2 different Python3 versions

Tags: python, python-3.x

I just reinstalled my macOS and downloaded the latest python version (3.9.1), but it turns out that I had already python 3 preinstalled (3.8.2). Now I have 2 different version and I access 3.8.2 with python3 (and pip3) and 3.9.1 with python3.9 (and pip3.9).

What I really want is to have single python3 version (3.9.1) and be able to access it with python3 (and pip3). My /usr/local/bin is the following:

[image]

How can I do what I want?
One idea is to delete python3, python3-config, pydoc3, pip3, idle3, and 2to3 and create aliases, but since I'm newbie I want to be sure it won't break anything and also if there is simpler solution.